# Killing a process within X seconds after starting

Tags: shell, scripting

It quite often happens to me, that when I start thinking about something while in front of my laptop, the screen lock will kick in - I tend to freeze when I think :) Then  I have to type my password to unlock my session, then I will freeze again while thinking, and then I repeat the whole process all over again :) I think this way I waste about a week of every year ;) Throw a stone at me if it never happened to you :)

So, I wanted to use `rofi -e "The screen is about to lock..."` to show the warning and then, after, let's say, 10 seconds, `slock` would be executed.

I did some testing and when I have two terinals open, I use `sleep 10; pkill rofi` in one of them, and `rofi -e "The screen is about to lock..." || slock` in the second one.

If I wait 10 seconds, rofi will be killed and slock will kick in. If I manage to react in 10 seconds and close rofi, `slock` will not run.

I've been trying to put this behaviour into a single script, which would be executed by `xidle` - now `xidle` simply executes `slock` after 300 seconds, but I wanted to have this warning message before executing `slock` - would you mind helping me to achieve this result?

Thanks in advance to all kind souls :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [GNU `timeout`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html):

```
timeout 10s rofi -e "The screen is about to lock..." || slock
```

If `rofi` exits within the ten seconds, `slock` won’t run (assuming `rofi` exits with exit code 0); otherwise, `timeout` will kill it and exit with a non-zero exit code, so `slock` will run.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've done it:

`rofi -e "The screen is about to lock..." & sleep 10; pkill rofi && slock`

And this script is called by `xidle`.